# Justification why $A\setminus B$, $A\cap B$ and $B \setminus A \in \mathcal{R}$ since in power set of $A\cup B$

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

In abstract measure theory, we defined $\mathcal{R}$ as a Ring on a set $X$ iff $\mathcal{R}$ is a subring of $(\mathcal{P}(X), \Delta, \cap)$. $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is the power set on $X$

What I do not understand: for $A,B$ in a ring $\mathcal{R}$ it is clear that $A\setminus B$, $A\cap B$ and $B \setminus A$ are in the ring **BECAUSE** they are a subset of $A\cup B$.

It is not clear to me why the Statement immediately follows from the fact that 
 $A\setminus B$, $A\cap B$ and $B \setminus A$ are a subset of  $A \cup B$.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where did you see such statement? 'because they are  a subset of $A\cup B$' is a wrong argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A \cup B = (A \Delta B) \Delta (A \cap B)$ is in $\mathcal{R}$ and $A \setminus B = (A \cup B) \Delta B$ is then also in $\mathcal{R}$ (likewise, $B \setminus A = (A \cup B) \Delta A$ is too).

But the *because* is weird, I agree. Just reason from the set algebra facts (Maybe because it's the first step and then we use that $C \subseteq D$ implies $D\setminus C = D \Delta C$ as I did)